# Из названия массива сделать функцию

Tags: массивы, функции, html, javascript

Вот кое как с вашей помощью состряпал такой код http://jsfiddle.net/3Pt34/2/ - только нужно вместо выводимого 'значения1' после фильтра нужно вставить калькулятор.Т.е. после фильтра выводится 'значение1' и калькулятор.Калькулятор почти готов, но не совсем пониаю как это сделать. Я понимаю дело в  ф-ции;

```
function rbvalue(html_name){
    var undefined, default_value, i, rb_collection = document.getElementsByName(html_name);
    if (rb_collection !== undefined) {
        default_value = rb_collection[0].value;
    }   
    for (i = 0; i < rb_collection.length; i++) {
        if (rb_collection[i].checked){
            return rb_collection[i].value;     
        }
    }   
    return default_value;
}
```

Но как её преобразовать что бы она не html код выдавала? Например что бы вместо значения1 можно было бы вставить ф-цию?

Comment: @нгш, я, конечно, код отформатировал, но постарайтесь в следующий раз делать это сами и не пихать его цитатой

Comment: @Etki, хорошо, спасибо